# Placeholder text field not showing in the Xcode inspector for the Helloworld example

Tags: xcode

I am trying the HelloWorld example from Apple using Xcode Version 4.6.3 (4H1503) but when I add the text field by dragging a text field object onto the canvas the inspector does not show the placeholder field.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.

Your probably not in the right inspector "section". Click the NSTextField you dragged out on the window and refer to the image below.

[image]

Comment: I was just careless and didn't notice I grabbed textview instead of text field - thanks